# How to show that if $\binom{n}{i} \gt \binom{n}{i+1} \Rightarrow i \ge \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil $

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, solution-verification

I'm not sure how to proof the above, proving it by contradiction feels most natural for me here, but I fail to get the contradiction.

$$\binom{n}{i} \gt \binom{n}{i+1} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!} \gt \frac{n!}{(i+1)!(n-i-1)!} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)(n-i-1)!} \gt \frac{n!}{(i+1)i!(n-i-1)!} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{(n-i)} \gt \frac{1}{i+1} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$i+1 \gt n-i \Leftrightarrow$$
$$2i+1 \gt n$$

Now we know $i \lt\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$, but $2\cdot \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil +1$ is definitely larger than $n$.

Comment: how did you go from $2i + 1 > n$ to $i < \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$?

Comment: @okzoomer, I'm trying to to proof via contradiction and therefore assumed $i \lt \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$.  If that leads to a contradiction, musn't $i \ge \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$?

Comment: If $n < 2i + 1$, then $n \le 2i$ or $n/2 \le i$.

Comment: @WhatAMesh I am not sure that you assumed anything up till $2i + 1 > n$. You don't need to use contradiction for every proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have so far correctly shown that $\binom ni\ge \binom n{i+1}\iff 2i+1>n$. To complete the proof, you just need to show $2i+1>n$ implies $i\ge \lceil n/2\rceil$. This is simple.
$$
\begin{align}
2i+1>n 
&\iff 2i\ge n
\\&\iff i\ge n/2
\\&\stackrel{\star}\iff i\ge \lceil n/2\rceil 
\end{align}
$$
For the starred step, note that $\lceil n/2\rceil$ is defined to be **the smallest** integer which is greater than $n/2$. Since $i\ge n/2$, we know that $i$ is **an** integer greater than $n/2$, we can conclude that $i$ is at least as big as the smallest such integer,  so $i\ge \lceil n/2\rceil$. Note that it is essential that $i$ is an integer for this proof to work.

Comment: Sry for commenting after accepting, but isn't $ \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ potentially larger than$\frac{n}{2}$? I think this can be fixed though with $2i + 1 > n \Leftrightarrow i+\frac{1}{2} \gt \frac{n}{2} \Leftrightarrow i \ge \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$

Comment: @WhatAMesh See edit for explanation.